# WinRT C# - create Converter string to string for binding Gridview

Tags: c#, binding, windows-runtime, converters

I come to you today for a "little" problem. I don't know how to create a simple converter because its the first time and I don't find a easy example.
I would like to create a converter "string to string" for a gridview binding. This is for an imagesource. I take from an object a string( which is the name of the image) and I would like to add the "full path" like :

```
 return "ms-appdata:///local/" + value;
```

This is actually what I did :

```
 class thumbToFullPathConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var fullPath = value;

        return ("ms-appdata:///local/" + value);
        Debug.WriteLine(value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Sorry, I think its a quick win but I don't know how to do this. Thanks for your time, Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want your class to inherit from the `IValueConverter` interface.

```
public class ThumbToFullPathConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {           
        if (value == null)            
            return value;

        return String.Format("ms-appdata:///local/{0}", value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You then need to include this converter in your XAML (either as a resource local to the page, or an app resource available throughout the app). Import the namespace where on the page(s) you want to access the converter. (Change `MyConverters` to your namespace)

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyConverters"
```

Then set it as a resource

```
<MyPage.Resources>
   <local:ThumbToFullPathConverter x:Key="ThumbToFullPathConverter" />
</MyPage.Resources>
```

Then you can use it where you like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText, Converter={StaticResource ThumbToFullPathConverter}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a class with this code. It will be your converter

```
public class ThumbToFullPathConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targettype, object parameter, string Path)
    {
        return ("ms-appdata:///local/" + value).ToString();
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targettype, object parameter, string Path)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now the below code will explain you how can you use it to bind image in gridview data template.

Add the page resource in you XAMl page.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:ThumbToFullPathConverter 
               x:Key="ThumbToFullPathConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
     <Image 
            Source="{Binding path, Converter={StaticResource ThumbToFullPathConverter}}"
            Stretch="None" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I don't know who to thanks, but thanks both that works and now I have a good idea of how its works !