# Windows Phone 8.1 highlight titles of some list elements by parameter

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I would like to highlight titles of my listview elements, but not all. Each element has a property which decides whether the title will be bold. I use MVVM. How do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DataTemplate

You can make a datatemplate for these listview items which can change the style based on the property, combine this with a [converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902304/winrt-c-sharp-create-converter-string-to-string-for-binding-gridview).

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfElements}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>  
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                           FontWeight="{Binding IsBold, Converter={StaticResource BoolToFontWeightConverter}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Then all you need to do is add a converter which returns the appropriate Font Weight for each item based off the property. You could also put this data template into a resource dictionary at the top of your file or in another file and then reference it by name if you wanted to.